# Chocolatey : how to handle major change in package and uninstallation on upgrade to new major version?

Tags: package, chocolatey, azcopy

I'm maintainer of azcopy chocolatey package. https://chocolatey.org/packages/azcopy
Microsoft released version 10 of azcopy (from version 8).

The tool is now a single exe (in a zip file).
The old one was a MSI installer.

The command line is completely different between v8 and v10.

I've got two choices :

- Create a new azcopy10 package for this package and have both living and at some point deprecate the old one
- Simply "upgrade" the azcopy package to v10 as I don't expect MS to upgrade v8 anymore. If people are willing to keep v8 they still can avoid upgrade (I was going this way)

In case I just upgrade the azcopy, how do I manage the upgrade ?

- If v8 is installed, do I uninstall it ? Is it allowed to uninstall a package in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 of a new version ?
- Do I just manage the actual installation of v10 and let v8 if already install?

Answer (score 0):

So, here are my thoughts on this...

Are these tools intended to be used side by side?  You say that there are differences in how the command line functions, so it sounds like maybe that is the case.  If you can use them side by side, then that in my opinion would be a case for a new, standalone package, named azcopy10.

That leaves the question on what to do with the existing azcopy package though.  Should this be changed to be azcopy8?  If so, should the existing azcopy package become a meta package, that points to either azcopy8 or azcopy10?  That would certainly fit with how some other packages out there work.

However, this leads us back to the question of what to do if azcopy is already installed...

If they "can" work side by side, then simply blowing away the existing installation probably isn't a good idea, as some people might want to have both installed.  As a result, a package parameter might be required to handle the uninstall if someone specifically chooses to uninstall it.

Long story short... There are lots of choices here, and there is unlikely to be one "correct" answer, as you will never please everyone.  Likely, this doesn't help you though :(